# Selecting a single value with multiple options in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select a single value based on dates when two `Line Number` values are the same in sequential order.

Here's a sqlfiddle just to show exactly how my tables are structured.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ccf800/1

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Line Number`
              , `Contract Number`
              , `Date Promised`
              , `roytecp_n`
           FROM otis_pos
          RIGHT 
           JOIN `otis rev link` 
             on otis_pos.`Item Number` = `otis rev link`.otis_pn
          WHERE otis_pos.`Contract Number` <> '' 
            AND (
  (`Date Promised` <= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 28 DAY 
    AND (roytecp_n Like 'OTH%' 
        OR roytecp_n Like '9O%' 
        OR roytecp_n Like '81%'
        OR roytecp_n is NULL
  ) 
  OR 
  ( `Date Promised` > CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 28 DAY
    AND (roytecp_n Like '88%' 
        OR roytecp_n Like '89%' 
        OR roytecp_n IS NULL
    )
  )
)
```

This returns both sets of values instead of one of the specified values.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
Line Number    Contract Number    Date Promised    roytecp_n
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600HZ974
   2               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600HZ974
   3               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600HY998
   3               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600HY998
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600DV998
   2               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600DV998
   3               648756          2020-01-24      9O04174AKV96-B
   3               648756          2020-01-24      OTHWC00DT998
```

Here's how the data needs to be returned when the values are greater than or equal to the current_date + 28 days:

```
Line Number    Contract Number    Date Promised    roytecp_n
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600HZ974
   3               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600HY998
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      89OTHW600DV998
   3               648756          2020-01-24      9O04174AKV96-B
   4               648756          2020-01-24      OTHWC00DT998
```

Here's how the data needs to be returned when the values are less than or equal to the current_date + 28 days

```
Line Number    Contract Number    Date Promised    roytecp_n
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600HZ974
   3               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600HY998
   1
   1               648756          2020-01-24    
   2               648756          2020-01-24      OTHW600DV998
   3               648756          2020-01-24      9O04174AKV96-B
   4               648756          2020-01-24      OTHWC00DT998
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a wrong (  at the first AND

```
  SELECT DISTINCT `Line Number`
                , `Contract Number`
                , `Date Promised`
                , `roytecp_n`
  FROM otis_pos
  RIGHT JOIN `otis rev link` 
               on otis_pos.`Item Number` = `otis rev link`.otis_pn
  WHERE otis_pos.`Contract Number` <> '' 
  AND (`Date Promised` <= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 28 DAY 
        AND (roytecp_n Like 'OTH%' 
            OR roytecp_n Like '9O%' 
            OR roytecp_n Like '81%'
            OR roytecp_n is NULL
      ) 
      OR 
      ( `Date Promised` > CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 28 DAY
        AND (roytecp_n Like '88%' 
            OR roytecp_n Like '89%' 
            OR roytecp_n IS NULL
        )
      )
    )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ccf800/3

Comment: Sorry, I must not have made my question clear. I need to select a single value based on the date criteria when there are two of the same line numbers back to back while keeping the line numbers in the sequential order it is in.

Comment: your comment is nor clear  ..  respect to my  sql code (that return two rows) which row you want ???